# Virtuemart: How to make link "Show Cart" dynamic?

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, show, cart, virtuemart

I have link "Show cart" static now
http://www.baytires.com/index.php?page=shop.cart

How can I make it dynamic, based on items added?

Comment: If I were you I would probably ask this on the Virtuemart forums. The guys there specialise in VirtueMart. And while we're all geniuses here, they know their own product better than us :)

Comment: well, they dont seem to help alot )

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code specifically, there is already a conditional statement in there based on the number of products in the cart since it displays "Your Cart is currently empty." until you put something in it. Find that part in the code and copy the logic for use on the link.